# R: drawing multiple things over one another

Tags: r

I have a data table and I want to do the following:

1) use xyplot to plot the data

2) use rasterimage to 'mark' certain regions in this plot as 'good' (green) or 'bad' (red)

This is what I got so far:

```
library(lattice)
dataFrame = data.frame(
  Z1 = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  Z2 = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))

dataFrameResult = data.frame(
  install=c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))


imageMatrix = matrix(
  c(rgb(255, 0, 0, alpha=100, maxColorValue = 255 ),rgb(0, 255, 0, alpha=100, maxColorValue = 255 ), 
    rgb(255, 0, 0, alpha=100, maxColorValue = 255 ),rgb(0, 0, 255, alpha=100, maxColorValue = 255 )), 
  nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE,)
image <- as.raster(imageMatrix)
fig = xyplot(Z1 ~ Z2, group = dataFrameResult$install, data=dataFrame)

plot.new()
print(fig, pos=c(0,0,1,1), more = TRUE)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(c(0, 3), c(0, 3), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
rasterImage(image, 0, 0, 1, 1, interpolate = FALSE)
```

This produces the following:
[image: screenshot]

In principal it looks fine but the positioning of the rasterImage function and the positioning of the xyplot do not match up... So, instead of guessing and pushing them around (does this procedure depend on the scales, etc.?) I thought that it can't be that hard to draw an image into a plot... right?

So anybody knows how to achieve the image below with (0,0) being (0,0) in and (1,1) being (1,1) in *both* scales? Or, even better, is there a way to draw an xyplot and tell R to paint the background in a user specified function like so...

```
getColor = function(x,y) {
  return(rgb(x, y, 0, 0, ...))
}
plot (backgroundColorFunction=getColor)
```

Cheers,

FW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an easier way is to use the normal plot function, and use the functions like rect() after your plot to mark the regions and points() to plot the data,
for example :

```
> plot(c(1, 5), c(0, 4), type= "n", xlab = "", ylab ="")
> rect( 2 ,3  , 3  , 4 , col ="green" , border="red" )
> points(c(1:5),c(0:4),col="blue")
> rect(1.8,2.8,2.3,3.4,col="white",border = "white")
```

that results :
[image: resulting plot]
you can customize your plot by changing the parameters and using your data inside this function. other functions to use after plot are :

plot.default, plot.window, points, lines, abline, axis, title, text, mtext, segments, symbols, arrows, polygon, rect, box, contour, filled.contour and image.

try search them in R help, easy to use :)

I've to mention that you can use this function for many times for one plot for example if you want to plot 2 rects just write two rect() function